# No TransformationSets configured error emerging while using maven xml:transform

Tags: xml, maven, xslt

I'm experiencing an issue that quite bothers me already while trying to utilize the maven XML plugin - Mojo codehous.

I have a POM file in the project containing below setup:

```
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>transform</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <transformationSets>
        <transformationSet>
          <dir>directory\to\files</dir>
          <stylesheet>\transformer\t_ssheet.xsl</stylesheet>
        </transformationSet>
      </transformationSets>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It's quite the same setup as it is in all examples I've found on the Internet, however, it still generates an error on my side.
While using command "mvn xml:transform" i got an error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:1.0.2:transform (default-cli) on project myProject: No TransformationSets configured. -> [Help 1]
```

Is anyone able to help me? I assume anyone can see that the sets are set (or I simply need to define them somewhere else as well).
Unfortunately, I could not find any answer for that, maybe it's too trivial to mention it anywhere, but still it's kind of a blocker for me.

Comment: That's very interesting.  The obvious thing to try is to replace `<TransformationSet>` with `<transformationSet>`.  Otherwise your configuration looks good to me.

Comment: @LairdNelson, actually the <TransformationSet> is pasted as such as I tried to use it instead of <transformationSet> ** I've edited the post to not confuse others

I have no clue what I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the thing was that I had a child POMs in modules listed in master POM.

Once I used a switch `-N` everything works fine. Thanks!